# Making UIImageView (Image of an arrow) pointing where I touch on the screen

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have tried too many equations to get the right answer, maybe something wrong with the code or my understanding of the idea. However, here is my code:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let coord = touch.location(in:view)
        self.linegu.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: atan((coord.y - (self.view.center.y + (self.view.center.y)/2.5)) / (coord.x - self.view.center.x)))
    }
}
```

`linegu` is the `UIImageView` I'm using and I position it in the middle of the view by using this code:

```
let Ypos = (self.view.center.y/2.5);
self.linegu.center = self.view.center
self.linegu.center.y = (self.view.center.y + Ypos)
```

[image: wherever I touch the screen, the arrow points toward a different point =(]

Comment: On the picture is not visible, but I guess that you are wrong at 90 degrees. Try adding or subtracting 90 degrees from the result. Please provide point where you tapped on the picture.

Comment: Maybe,you need to provide a project.

I create a demo project with your code.
And it's worked. 

https://github.com/sunbohong/Demo-Collection/commit/3ed6f593a1fa3dde5e489165821033ed6e02631f#diff-86182cc774e7f14dc3e6cf106edaa8f1

Comment: I will try to subtract maybe I can get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter where the image view is located. And you should throw away your "magic number" 2.5. You are way overthinking this.

Assume `arrow` is the image view, and that it starts out life horizontal with the arrow pointing to the right. And assume that the background view has a tap gesture recognizer on it. (We use a tap gesture recognizer for simplicity; it looks like you might eventually want to use a pan gesture recognizer. But for now, let's just get this thing working.)

Then here is how the tap gesture's action handler would look:

```
    let c = self.arrow.center
    let p = t.location(in: self.arrow.superview)
    let angle = atan2(p.y - c.y, p.x - c.x)
    self.arrow.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:angle)
```

It's as simple as that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you answer helped a lot.

Comment: But the angle not accurate enough :(        please see this link   http://gph.is/2qz4dgI

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. _Touches_ are not very exact (your finger is fat), but the math is precise. And the line in my screencast is pointing right where I clicked.

Comment: lol I recorded from the simulator xD my fingers are skinny. I am confused but I will fix it. Anyway your answer was good enough to put me on the right track, thanks matt.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use this weird formula?

```
CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: atan((coord.y - (self.view.center.y + (self.view.center.y)/2.5)) / (coord.x - self.view.center.x)))
```

And where does this `2.5` divider come from?

---

What about just using `.center` or `.frame` to position the `UIImageView`?

Like:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let location = touch.location(in: view)
        imageView.center = location // may need to apply some offset here, depending on where exactly the arrow points in the arrow image
    }
}
```

Comment: The formula is basically the angle between two points. tan-1[(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)]

Comment: 2.5 is to get the arrow lower in the y-axis

Comment: Hence, y1 and x1 represents fixed points where I already have assigned these fixed points in the code

Comment: I need the arrow to point where I touch, I used the formula tan-1[(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)] to get the angle from my fixed point to the point where I touch then I used "CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle:angle)" to rotate the arrow, but I failed =(

Comment: Ah ok, I thought you want to position the arrow wherever you touched.. Didn't realize you want to rotate it to that point. In that case matt's answer seems to be correct to me.